# How to read a BLOB with qt-type compression?

Tags: qt, compression, binaryfiles

I have a file (about 100k files, to be specific) containing a data from weather radars - one file is a one radar image. It is a mosaic of data from several radars, creating a map of a reflectivity over whole country.
The files have extension .cmax and I need to convert them to something more useful (eg. array of reflectivities) for further uses.

I have asked data provider how to read those files. They responded:

> The standard product format in our system (.cmax) is the internal format of the company that provides us with the software. It consists of an xml and binary part. It can be read by reading as a stream of bytes. Firstly, parse the initial bytes as xml, then treat the rest (BLOBs) as a binary data compressed with the "qt" method. You need to unpack them using a library that supports this compression mode. In general, you have to work a little, but it can be done in virtually any programming language.

The main issue is with the binary part of data. I have tried to decompress it with zlib (googling qt compression it comes out) and reading as a binary data in C++. None of them worked. It also doesn't seem resonable to me to try reading that data as binary in Qt.

The file begins with those lines:

```xml
<product version="5.44.5" datetime="2017-01-01T18:00:00" datatype="dBZ" type="cmax" name="CMAX" owner="">
   <data time="18:00:00" date="2017-01-01">
```

Then, there are radars specifications and image details (active radars, min and max reflectivity etc). XML part ends with:

```xml
</product>
<!-- END XML -->
<BLOB blobid="0" size="79617" compression="qt">(here are lots of binary data)</BLOB>
```

I'm looking for a way (tool?) to convert that binary data. For example, it could be that mentioned library.

Comment: Looking at the details, this is most likely Leonardo (Selex/Gematronic) Rainbow5 format. zlib is the right lib for decompression. But there are some tricks to it. A python reader is implemented in the wradlib library (https://github.com/wradlib). Maybe you can adapt from that code. Disclaimer: I'm one of the wradlib devs.

Comment: @kmuehlbauer Can you post your comment as an answer, so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the details, this is most likely Leonardo (Selex/Gematronic) Rainbow5 format. zlib is the right lib for decompression. But there are some tricks to it. A python reader is implemented in the wradlib library (https://github.com/wradlib). Maybe you can adapt from that code. Disclaimer: I'm one of the wradlib devs.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try simply using the qUncompress() function? https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qbytearray.html#qUncompress

Comment: Yes, I tried. But it gives "Data is corrupted" error. Documentation also suggests prepending data with length of uncompressed data. However, just QByteArray.prepend doesn't solve the issue.
So, I'm not sure whether the problem is that data should be uncompressed using other method or should it be prepared in a specific way.